# Google Indexing API with Postman

Tags: indexing, postman, google-indexing-api

I want to use Postman to send request to Google Indexing API.
After Request headers were successfully updated with authorization data for preview.

In Postman : 
[image]

I'm following  Google Indexing API document : https://developers.google.com/search/apis/indexing-api/v3/using-api

After sending request POST in Postman, I stuck at this error.
Please help me

Comment: You dont need the double quotes for keys and values in postman

Comment: I removed double quotes, but this still error Missing attribute  URL

Comment: Also you are suppose to post the payload body as JSON, not `form-data`

Answer (score 0):

The key value pair doesn't need double quotes.

And the body should be submitted as 'raw JSON' instead of 'form-data'.

[image]

More information can be read here:
https://developers.google.com/search/apis/indexing-api/v3/using-api